Why do two global variables have the same address?
Why do a and b have the same address?
Here is my program:
section .data

a resw 0
b resw 0

section .bss

section .text

global main
main:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

I run the program in the debugger and stop at the start of the main function. I print the addresses of a and b and it's the same:
(gdb) print &a
$1 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x404028 <completed>
(gdb) print &b
$2 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x404028 <completed>

I compiled the program and ran it in the debugger like this:
yasm -g dwarf2 -f elf64 tmp.asm -l tmp.lst
gcc -no-pie tmp.o -o tmp
gdb tmp

I am running Linux Mint 21.3.

resw takes the number of words to reserve. You reserved 0 hence the same address. Since you are in .data you likely wanted dw 0
